# What is needed for using nested elements in CSS file?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Somewhere I saw this structure of CSS document:

```
header {
  .navigation {
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}
```

If I will try it in my CSS file, it doesn't work.
What is needed for ability to write this code?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like LESS CSS http://lesscss.org/

You have to import javascript file less.js into your page.

Comment: Well, I added the JS file to my website, I renamed the `app.css` to `app.less` (also with attribute `rel="stylesheet/less"`), I put also the block of JS code into my website, but it doesn't working... no styles are loaded from my LESS file. Paths are correct, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Now compile your css file and than apply Mr **@ozkanozlu** is right way

**just do this**

```
header {.navigation{a{text-decoration: none;}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've quoted is not actually CSS, it is a language called [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which compiles to CSS; it is a CSS pre-processor. It is designed to make CSS easier to work with, but it needs to be converted to pure CSS before it will actually work in a browser.

LESS can be compiled to CSS before deployment -- ie so you work on LESS code, but the user sees standard CSS -- or provided to the browser as LESS, but with the less.js also compiler included in the page. For performance reasons, I would always prefer the first of those options.

Other similar languages also exist -- see [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) for example. You can see a comparison of SASS vs LESS here: http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/